# How to specify form field settings but still get verbose_name and help_text from the model

Tags: django, forms

I have a Django model that specifies the `verbose_name` and `help_text`; I want this information to be used in the Form for the model while also specifying additional information for the field in the form class.

The problem I'm having is that as soon as I add additional attributes to a form field I lose the `verbose_name` and `help_text`, meaning I have to specify them in the model *and* the form, which does not seem very DRY to me.

The model field is defined as:

```
class DataSubmission(models.Model):
    ...
    upload_date = models.DateField(blank=True,
                                   null=True,
                                   help_text='Date of submission',
                                   verbose_name='Upload date')
```

When the Form field is only defined in the `Meta.fields` the `verbose_name` appears as the form field label and the `help_text` can be accessed as well.

When as I define the Form as follows (the `DatePicker` widget is my own code):

```
class DataSubmissionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    upload_date = forms.DateField(input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS,
                                  required=False,
                                  widget=DatePicker)
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = DataSubmission
        fields = (
            ...
            'upload_date',
            ...
        )
```

I lose the `verbose_name` and `help_text` from the model. How can I modify the form field without losing the information from the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problems were caused by defining form fields as class variables, when I should be using the inner `Meta` class to modify the field behaviour.

I was probably following some tutorial or sample code I found when I defined the form fields in that way; but the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields) give me the answer (if only I'd read it carefully in the first place!):

> To specify a custom widget for a field, use the widgets attribute of
>   the inner Meta class. This should be a dictionary mapping field names
>   to widget classes or instances.

That comment lead me to experiment with the other field settings I was using, by adding them to the `Meta` class.

So once I had converted the field declaration to:

```
class DataSubmissionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DataSubmission
        fields = (
            ...
            'upload_date',
            ...
        ) 
        input_formats = (
            'upload_date': settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS,
        )
        required = (
            'upload_date': False,
        )
        widget = (
            'upload_date': DatePicker
        )
```

The `verbose_name` and `help_text` became available again.